# .NET Core - How do I read a file that requires credentials

Tags: .net-core, impersonation

I need to be able to read a file, using .NET Core, that requires credentials (username & password). While my app may be running anywhere, it is reading files at times from a Windows \server\share.

In standard .NET we do this by first trying impersonation and if that fails, an explicit Windows API login call. I understand that neither of these make sense in a .NET Core world because they're very operating system dependent.

Is there a way to do this in .NET Core? Or does the .NET Core world want all files read via http?

[Also asked on MSDN.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9b49f71-5c95-4e44-a8f3-8aece5a8ca87/net-core-how-do-i-read-a-file-that-requires-credentials?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: is it entrypted and password protected  through zip  or  any special format file  e.g.  excel file

Comment: @divyang4481 THe file itself is not encrypted. Access to the \\server\share is what requires credentials.

Comment: you can use samba client  to connect with shared drive from linux and access file 
http://sharpcifsstd.dobes.jp/

Comment: @divyang4481 I need the ability to read from Windows servers.

Comment: yes samba client is user to read from window server's  shared drive from linux

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/mj1856/SimpleImpersonation which is under MIT